# Particle in a 1D Box with Symmetric potential: How find solutions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

I am working on a problem in which I shall find the normalised solution to the 1D particle in a box. Solving for the particle in an asymmetric potential is quite straight forward, but I run into trouble when the potential is symmetric:

$$
V(x) = \begin{cases} \infty & x < -\tfrac{L}{2} \\ 0 & - \frac{L}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{L}{2} \\ \infty & x > \frac{L}{2} \end{cases}
$$

The problems arise with the boundary conditions. We have

$$
\frac{d^2\Psi (x)}{dx^2} = -k^2 \Psi (x)
$$

where $k^2 = \frac{2mE}{\hbar ^2}$. The general solution is

$$
\Psi (x) = Ae^{ikx} + Be^{-ikx}
$$

Due to continuity and the nature of the potential, we must have

$$
\psi (-\tfrac{L}{2}) = \Psi (\tfrac{L}{2}) = 0
$$

Plugging in:

$$
\psi (-\tfrac{L}{2}) = Ae^{-ikL/2} + Be^{ikL/2} = 0 \\
\psi (\tfrac{L}{2}) = Ae^{ikL/2} + Be^{-ikL/2} = 0
$$

I know that when the potential is symmetric, we will find even ($A=B$) and odd ($A=-B$) wave functions. We will see that for even functions, $n$ has to be odd whole numbers, and for odd functions $n$ has to be even whole numbers. This leads to a sequence of sine and cosine curves as $n$ increases by 1.

I am trouble getting there, however, from those boundary conditions, and I would really appreciate pointers and help.

Answer (score 8):

[Giorgi Butbala's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/112560/81133) in terms of sines and cosines is perfectly correct.  But just to prove that it can be done, here's how you'd proceed from your two equations in terms of $A$ and $B$:

The first equation shows that you must have
$$
B = - e^{-ikL} A
$$
and plugging this in to the second equation yields
$$
A e^{ikL/2} - A e^{-3 ikL/2} = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad  A e^{ikL/2} (1 - e^{-2ikL}) = 0.
$$
Here's the important part:  the only way for this equation to hold is for either $A = 0$ (which means $B = 0$ and we have no wavefunction at all), or for $e^{-2iKL} = 1$.  This latter condition implies that $2 i k L = 2 i n \pi$, where $n$ is an integer.  Thus, we get that $k = n\pi/L$ as before, and $B = - e^{-in\pi}A$.   In the cases where $n$ is even, we have $B = - A$, and 
$$
\psi(x) = A (e^{ikx} - e^{-ikx}) = 2 i A \sin kx;
$$
in the cases where $n$ is odd, we have $B = A$, and
$$
\psi(x) = A (e^{ikx} + e^{-ikx}) = 2 A \cos kx.
$$
The normalization of the wave functions then proceeds as before.

Oh, and if you want to look at this in even more generality:  You can rewrite your equations above in terms of a matrix equation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} e^{-ikL/2} & e^{ikL/2} \\ e^{ikL/2} & e^{-ikL/2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix} = 0.
$$
Now, if this matrix were invertible, you would be able to multiply both left-hand and right-hand side by the inverse and get $A = B = 0$.  It follows then that if we want to have a non-zero solution, the matrix must not be invertible, i.e., its determinant must be zero.  This works out to be
$$
e^{-ikL} - e^{ikL} = 0
$$
and so we must have $kL = n\pi$, as before.  Again, we're using the fact that we want our wavefunction coefficients to be non-zero to constrain the possible values of $k$.

Comment: +1 for acknowledging i in 2iAsinkx. Often, solutions just throw c1*coskx+c2*sinkx at you without justification. Of course, we can define A in terms of a pure real constant C to get  A=(-i/2)C, so you get back Csinkx. I think this distinction is important though, as the Euler formula mandates an imaginary coefficient of the sine term.

Answer (score 5):

So our wavefuction is $\Psi\left(0\right)=e^{ikx}=C\cos\left(kx\right)+D\sin\left(kx\right)$, and potential barrier is: 
$$
V\left(x\right) = \begin{cases} \infty & x < -\tfrac{L}{2} \\ 0 & - \frac{L}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{L}{2} \\ \infty & x > \frac{L}{2} \end{cases}
$$
 We know that wavefuction is zero when $x=-\frac{L}{2}$ or $x=\frac{L}{2}$, 
$$
\Psi\left(\frac{L}{2}\right)=C\cos\left(k\frac{L}{2}\right)+D\sin\left(k\frac{L}{2}\right)=\Psi\left(-{L\over 2}\right)=0\tag{1.1}
$$
**Solving for even $n$:**

And in that case $k=\frac{n\pi}{L}$, (when we use that $k$ and and $D=0$ it satisfies the equation). So we have $\Psi\left(x\right)=C\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$. So now we have to calculate constant $C$. We can use this equation:
$$
\int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{{L\over 2}}|\Psi\left(x\right)|^2dx=1
$$
So now lets apply it to equation:
$$
\int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{{L\over 2}}C^2\cos^2\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{L\sin\left(n\pi\right)}{\pi n}+L\right)C^2=\frac{C^2L}{2}=1
$$
So constant $C=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}$. So wavefunction is $\Psi_{even}\left(x\right)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$

**Solving for odd $n$:**

in that case $k=\frac{2n\pi}{L}$ (this $k$ and setting $C=0$ satisfies equation $(1.1)$) and we get wavefunction $\Psi=Dsin(\frac{2n\pi x}{L})$. So now lets integrate:
$$
\int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}}D^2sin^2(\frac{2n\pi x}{L}) dx= \frac{1}{4}L\left(2-\frac{sin(2\pi n)}{\pi n}\right)D^2=\frac{D^2L}{2}=1
$$
So $D=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}$ ans wavefunction for odd $n$ is $\Psi_{odd}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}sin(\frac{2n\pi x}{L})$

**Conclusion(Answers):**

So now we have calculated two wavefunctions, one for odd $n$'s and one for even $n$'s
$$
\Psi_{even}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})
$$
and
$$
\Psi_{odd}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}sin(\frac{2n\pi x}{L})
$$

Comment: So you set $D=0$ because both cos and sin cannot equal 0 at the same time here. Also, cos has the property: cos(-x) = cos(x). Sin does not have that property. For this to work, have you set $\frac{kL}{2} = n\frac{\pi}{2}$ where $n=1,3,5, \ldots$? So what would be the solution for the even numbers of $n$?

Comment: For even numbers $k=\frac{2n\pi}{L}$ and wavefunction will be $\Psi=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}sin(\frac{2n\pi x}{L})$

Comment: Thanks. Was my reasoning in the comment above correct?

Comment: Thanks! I understand now how to solve the system! I appreciate it.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that your n in the even solution is actually also taking odd values? Otherwise I would suggest taking $2n \to n$. If n is understood as being even then $\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L})$ would be the correct solution (and your solution would only give half of the even wave-functions).