# Translation invariance of a quantum system.

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, potential

Computing the Schrodinger equation for a particle into the infinite potential well of width L

$$\begin{align*}
V(x) &= 0 & 0<x<L\\ 
 &= \infty & \text{otherwise}
\end{align*}$$

We get the following eigenfunctions of the hemiltonian operator,

$$\psi_n(x)=M \sin{\frac{n\pi}{L}x},$$

while the related eigenvalues for $n=1,2,...$, are

$$E_n=\frac{\hbar^2 \pi^2 n^2}{2mL^2}.$$

In the other hand, performing the same calculation for a potential centered in the origin

$$\begin{align*}
V(x) &= 0 & -\frac{L}{2}<x<\frac{L}{2}\\ 
 &= \infty & \text{otherwise}
\end{align*}$$

we obtain

$$\psi_n(x)=M \cos{\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{L}x}, \; \; E_n=\frac{\hbar^2 \pi^2 (2n-1)^2}{2mL^2}.$$

How is it possible that for the exactly same system we obtain different results? Did I make calculation mistakes or am I misunderstanding the principles?

Comment: You forgot that in the second case you also have $\sin$ waves as solutions, and not only cosines that gives you the even energy levels that you are missing

Comment: I don't see them, could you show me how to derive such solutions?

Comment: See this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112553/particle-in-a-1d-box-with-symmetric-potential-how-find-solutions or this http://www.physicspages.com/2012/08/09/infinite-square-well-centered-coordinates/

Comment: I still don't get it, my solution is true for both even and odd positive integers greater then zero. Adding together the two boundary conditions $$\begin{cases} 
A e^{-ikL}+B e^{ikL}=0 \\
A e^{ikL}+B e^{-ikL} = 0
\end{cases}$$ we get  $$(A+B)e^{\frac{ikL}{2}}+(A+B)e^{-\frac{ikL}{2}}=0,$$ and by the Euler's formula it becomes $$ 2(A+B) \cos{\frac{kL}{2}}=0.$$ Which is satisfied (avoiding the trivial solutions) if $$\frac{kL}{2}=n \pi-\frac{\pi}{2}, \; \; n=1,2,...$$

Comment: Try subtracting them and see what happens

Comment: Since the cosine parity, I can just check what happen at $x=\frac{L}{2}$. $$n=1 \Rightarrow \cos \frac12 \pi=0,$$ $$n=2 \Rightarrow \cos \frac32 \pi=0,$$ $$n=3 \Rightarrow \cos \frac52 \pi=0...$$ Right?

Comment: You need to subtract the two solutions with the exponentials, you'll get a sine solution that will give you different energy levels from those you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the boundary conditions

$$\begin{cases}  A e^{-ikL}+B e^{ikL}=0 \\ A e^{ikL}+B e^{-ikL} = 0 \; .\end{cases}$$

Adding and subtracting the two equation each other, we get

$$\begin{cases}  (A+B)e^{\frac{ikL}{2}}+(A+B)e^{-\frac{ikL}{2}}=0 \\ (B-A)e^{\frac{ikL}{2}}-(B-A)e^{-\frac{ikL}{2}}=0 \;.\end{cases}$$

By the Euler's formula

$$\begin{cases}  2(A+B)\cos \frac{kL}{2}=0 \\ 2i(B-A)\sin \frac{kL}{2}=0 \;.\end{cases}$$

The first is true for

$$\frac{kL}{2}=\frac{n \pi}{2}, \;\; n=1,3,...$$

while the second

$$\frac{kL}{2}=\frac{n \pi}{2}, \;\; n=2,4,...$$

These yield an energy eigenvalues formula with the same form of the shifted infinite potential well

$$E_n=\frac{\hbar^2 \pi^2 n^2}{2mL^2}, \; \; n=1,2,3,...$$

although the eigenfunction are

$$\psi_n(x)=\begin{cases}  2(A+B)\cos \frac{n \pi}{L}x & n \text{ odd}\\ 2i(B-A)\sin \frac{n\pi}{L}x & n \text{ even}\end{cases},\;\; n=1,2,3,...$$.