# Finding normalized eigenfunctions of a particle in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Here’s the problem:

> Find the normalized eigenfunctions and corresponding energy levels for a particle of mass $m$ moving under the potential $V(x) =0$ for $ x \in (-a,a)$ and $V(x) = \infty $ otherwise.

Here’s my work:

Solving the stationary state SE is a routine job. I get :

$\psi(x) = A \sin(rx) + B \cos(rx)$, where $r= \frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}$. I now want to enforce the boundary conditions $\psi(a)= \psi(-a) =0$.

(1): $\psi(a) = A \sin(ra) + B \cos(ra)$ and

(2): $\psi(-a)= -A \sin(ra) +B \cos(ra)$.

This is where I get confused:

Adding (1) and (2) I obtain $\cos(ra)=0 $ so that the energies are $E_{n}= \frac{n^2 \hbar^2 \pi^2}{8ma^2}$ for odd integers $n$. In this case the normalized eigenfunctions are $\psi(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{a}} \cos(rx)$.

However ( and this is what confuses me) when I instead subtract (2) from (1) I get $\sin(ra)=0$ so that the energy eigenvalues are $E_{n}= \frac{n^2 \pi^2 \hbar^2}{2ma^2}$ for even integers $n$. The normalized eigenfunctions now are $\psi(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{a}} \sin (rx)$.

Does this mean that my wave function is split up into either cos or sin depending on the parity of n? Can someone explain this to me. Many thanks!

Comment: Related:  [Particle in a 1D Box with Symmetric potential: How find solutions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112553/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $A sin(ra) \pm B cos(ra) = 0$ ; This implies that $Asin(ra) = 0$   and $Bcos(ra) = 0$.  The trivial solution to these two equations is $A=B=0$.

For a non-trivial solution at least one of $A$ and $B$ have to be non-zero. Hence, we can choose : $A = 0$ , $cos(ra) = 0$  , or  ,    $B=0$   , $sin(ra) = 0$ .

If we want *both* $A\neq 0$  and $B\neq 0$, then, of course, we'd have to have $sin(ra) = 0$     *and*     $cos(ra) = 0$, which has no solutions for $r$. So, we may choose *only one* of $A$ and $B$ to be non zero.

So, your conclusion is basically correct. This also should not be surprising. All eigenstates satisfy $\psi_n(a) = \psi_n(-a) = 0$;   The $n$ signifies the number of local extrema in the solution between $-a$ and $a$

It is easy to convince yourself (without solving anything, just by sketching a picture) that if you try to fit $n = 2m+1$ local extrema between $a$ and $-a$, you should end up with an even function with one (central) extremum on $x=0$. That is, $cos$. On the other hand, if you try to fit $n=2m$ extrema between the boundaries, you should end up with an odd function, that is, $sin$.