# Do wave functions of scattering states of a symmetric potential exhibit definite parity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, parity

My question is quite simple. Suppose we are given a potential such as a potential barrier (potential $V = V_0, -a \leq x \leq a$ and 0 otherwise). Will scattering states which are solutions to this potential exhibit definite parity ($\psi(x) = \pm\psi(-x)$)?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112553/50583

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13980/2451

Comment: I did not feel that this was a duplicate since the question you have linked to talks about bound states whereas my question relates to scattering states

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, Of course! Since
$$V(x)=V(-x)\rightarrow \psi(x)=\pm \psi(-x)$$

Comment: Can you prove this implication? In general, symmetries of the action/Lagrangian/potential do *not* need to be symmetries of the solutions to the equations of motion!